# Is this a tick?

Tags: entomology, arachnology

My dog has been vomiting today and I recently found this insect/arachnid near his dog bowl. Since vomiting is one of the symptoms of a tick bite, I am concerned that this insect/arachnid is a tick. Unfortunately, since I've crushed it partially, it's hard to tell how many legs it has and what it actually is. Additionally, I'm aware that tick larvae can have 6 legs and the older ticks have 8. Below are some photos next to an Australian $2 coin, which has a 2cm diameter. P.S. This tick should be "native" to Australia.

Do you guys think this is a Tick? Could it be a flea?

[image][image][image]

Comment: This insect is squished beyond recognition for me.

Comment: No beetles are of any know threat to dogs. They eat plants and detritus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, neither a tick nor a flea. That is a little beetle, and would have nothing to do with your dog's symptoms.